# Can Azure Data Factory v2 work without Integration Runtime if hosted in the same Resource Group?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have an OData feed on port 7048 hosted in a specific Azure resource group. It is not publicly accessible, but other servers within the same resource group can talk to each other.

I have added an Azure Data Factory v2 within the same resource group, and I was expecting it to be able to read the OData feed. However when I click on test connection I get:

```
Connection failed
[{"code":10201,"message":"Failed to create OData connection to **********"}]
```

There isn't much more information about this error anywhere.

The Integration Runtime is the default AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime.

Do I need another Integration Runtime, even though they are running on the same Resource Group? If not what does this error code 10201 mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error code is internal error code used for troubleshooting, but the error message is for customer read. You could make the OData source to Azure IP accessible so that AutoResourceIntegrationRuntime could access. Another option is create a selfhosted IR and allow the selfhosted IR's IP to access the OData source.